# How do I make a ControlTemplate (for a checkbox) readonly in WPF/MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, controltemplate

I've got a WPF datagrid where I've created a ControlTemplate for a checkbox to represent a `bool?` type. 
I'd like for the checkbox/control template to readonly to the user, but be able to change the value

Here's the template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="checkboxTemplate" TargetType="CheckBox">
    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
        <Rectangle x:Name="r" Height="10" Width="40" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RadiusX="4" RadiusY="4"></Rectangle>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="CheckBox.IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FF66D660" TargetName="r"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="CheckBox.IsChecked" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FFD50005" TargetName="r"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="CheckBox.IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="SlateGray" TargetName="r"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Here's the implementation in the datagrid:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn SortMemberPath="IsReady" Header="Ready" CanUserSort="True" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsReady, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Template="{StaticResource checkboxTemplate}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: You want your CheckBox to be ReadOnly, but you want the User to be able to change it's Checked value? Why do you want it ReadOnly then? Just for the style?

Comment: @Rachel: read-only to the user, editable from code.

Comment: @jberger I thought you were the OP so posted an answer based on your comment. Realize now that you aren't, so answer may not apply to his situation.

Answer (score 3):

You can either set IsHitTestVisible="false" or IsEnabled="false" on the checkbox.

Comment: Perfect simple solution

Comment: Not a perfect solution. Moving the focus to the checkbox and pressing the space bar key toggles it even if the IsHitTestVisible=False

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to make it readonly to move it behind some control with almost transparent background.

```
<DataTemplate>
  <Border Opacity="0.01" Background="White">
   <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsReady, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Template="{StaticResource checkboxTemplate}" />
  </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Yep, agree, IsEnabled="false" much easier :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're editing the Checked value from code, you should be editing the binding source (`IsReady`), and not the `CheckBox.Checked` value. Setting `MyCheckBox.Checked` will overwrite the binding, and not save the change to your `IsReady` property.

It's preferred to change the `IsReady` property from your ViewModel, but if you must do it from behind the View I usually cast the CheckBox's DataContext to my data object, and set the bound property from there

Something like this:

```
((MyDataObject)MyCheckBox.DataContext).IsReady = false;
```

As for making a CheckBox read-only to the user, set it's `IsEnabled` property to false

```
<CheckBox x:Name="MyCheckBox" IsEnabled="False" IsChecked="{Binding IsReady}" />
```

Comment: I think that `IsReady` should be updated from the ViewModel only (and not in View code casting to ViewModel type).